# Android Map Application : i cant run

Tags: android, google-maps

```
02-06 14:08:29.678: W/dalvikvm(702): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nhexia.pack/nhexia.pack.SaturnVTDActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nhexia.pack.SaturnVTDActivity
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nhexia.pack.SaturnVTDActivity
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
02-06 14:08:29.718: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  ... 11 more
```

i got this error when im run my application.... help

Comment: Fix your post, and show some effort on your part.

Comment: Try moving your legs very fast. (I'm sorry, couldn't help it.)

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file to make sure that the activity `nhexia.pack.SaturnVTDActivity` is declared correctly.

Comment: It is better to not edit the first question, but post a new one with a more appropriate title. It is OK to link to your previous question. As for your new question, findViewById fails to find an element. Which line of code causes the problem? Are all resources properly defined?

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible that you updated the ADT plugin and need to move your includes around as [this link suggests](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to launch a class which cannot be found. Is the activity defined in the manifest, is the class misspelled?

Try debug in eclipse and see what line it fails on, and share that in here.